# Get monitor output name from Gdk

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gtk, gtk3

My xrandr configuration is

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
```

~/.config/monitors.xml

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>LG IPS FULLHD</product>
          <serial>704NTFA9H451</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>LG FULL HD</product>
          <serial>508NTTQCZ625</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

With Gdk i get information

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import  Gdk, GdkX11

display = Gdk.Display.get_default()

print('manufacturer', 'model', 'output')
for m in range(display.get_n_monitors()):
    monitor = Gdk.Display.get_monitor(display, m)
    print(
        monitor.get_manufacturer(),
        monitor.get_model(),
        GdkX11.X11Monitor.get_output(monitor)
        )
```

Outputs

```
manufacturer model output
GSM HDMI-1 66
GSM DP-1 68
```

Why output name on model property? Is this same on other distributions, Gtk version, other DM or Wayland and Xorg ? Can i convert integer from GdkX11.X11Monitor.get_output() to name suitable for xrandr and monitors.xml?

Can I rotate monitor using gir ?

Gtk 3.24 Xorg-server 1.20.11